# Unix Loop if Condition and exit comand

Tags: unix

I am facing an issue, I have to delete files from some folders given in Path.lst, 
The entire script is working fine but when  some wrong path is given in Path.lst the script does exits out of the loop and perform no operation on the next paths.

But the last line

```
echo -e "\n ENDING SCRIPT SUCCESSFULLY ON `date` " >> $LOG_FILE
```

gets executed because exit 1 is not working in this part

```
if [ ! -d $path ]       
then
echo -e "\nERROR :$path IS INVALID." >> $LOG_FILE

echo -e "\nENDING SCRIPT WITH ERRORS ON `date`" >> $LOG_FILE
exit 1

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
THE SCRIPT IS LIKE :

echo -e "\nSTARTING SCRIPT ON `date`">> $LOG_FILE

if  [ $1 -gt 0 ]
then
DAYS_BFOR="$1"
else
echo -e "\nERROR :Please pass a single positive integer to the script" >>$LOG_FILE
echo -e "\nENDING SCRIPT WITH ERRORS ON `date` " >> $LOG_FILE

exit
fi

cat Path.lis | sed 's|^PATH[0-9]*=||g' |  while read path
do
if [ ! -d $path ]
then
echo -e "\nERROR :$path IS INVALID." >> $LOG_FILE
echo -e "\n ENDING SCRIPT WITH ERRORS ON `date` " >> $LOG_FILE

exit 1
else
echo -e "\nFILES DELETED FROM THE "$path" DIRECTORY --" >> $LOG_FILE

find $path -type f -mtime +$DAYS_BFOR  -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %kKB %p\n" | column -t | sed "s|"$path"||g" >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1

file_count=`find $path -type f -mtime +$DAYS_BFOR | wc -l`

if [ $file_count -ge 1 ]
then
find $path -type f -mtime +$DAYS_BFOR  | xargs rm 2>>$LOG_FILE 2>&1
fi
fi

done

echo Exit Status : $?
echo -e "\n ENDING SCRIPT SUCCESSFULLY ON `date`" >> $LOG_FILE
```

---

Please help and explain the reason as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the "ENDING SCRIPT SUCCESSFULLY" message to appear if files were successfully deleted, not if an invalid path was given you could just move the last two echo lines up to the end of the else statement like this:

```
 else
            echo -e "\nFILES DELETED FROM THE "$path" DIRECTORY --" >> $LOG_FILE
            find $path -type f -mtime +$DAYS_BFOR  -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %kKB %p\n" | column -t | sed "s|"$path"||g" >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1
            file_count=`find $path -type f -mtime +$DAYS_BFOR | wc -l`

            if [ $file_count -ge 1 ]
            then
                    find $path -type f -mtime +$DAYS_BFOR  | xargs rm 2>>$LOG_FILE 2>&1
            fi

            echo Exit Status : $?
            echo -e "\n--------------------------- ENDING SCRIPT SUCCESSFULLY ON `date` ----------------------------------" >> $LOG_FILE

    fi

done
```

If you want to just skip to the next item in the Path.lis file then just remove the exit statement from the first loop.  That way it will continue to execute the script until all the lines in the file have been read, and just show an error if the current file is not a valid path.

Comment: I just want the log file should show invalid path provided even if there is a single invalid path is present in the Path.lis as it is show two lines currently

Comment: if you remove the exit 1 statement, it would probably make sense to also remove the second echo statement - "ENDING SCRIPT WITH ERRORS"... in which case you would only have one error line written to the log file for each invalid path in Path.lis

Comment: But then how will I come to know that the path is invalid